# What is the role of "that" leading the sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

This is a sentence in the Queen's speech regarding the fight against Covid-19. It starts with a "that" which I think is not necessary. As "the attributes" already serve as the subject of the sentence, then what is the role of "That"?

> I hope in the years to come everyone will be able to take pride in how
> they responded to this challenge. And those who come after us will say
> the Britons of this generation were as strong as any. ***That* the
> attributes of self-discipline, of quiet good-humoured resolve and of
> fellow-feeling still characterise this country.** The pride in who we
> are is not a part of our past, it defines our present and our future.

Comment: It’s not a complete sentence, but its purpose is to connect it with “what those who come after us will say”  They will say ***that*** the attributes ...

Comment: I can understand if it is connected with the preceding sentence with a comma. But is it considered properly written as is as a transcript of an official speeh, leaving a sentence incomplete.

Comment: We Britons are more likely to be concerned with the sentiment of the speech than about nit-picking the grammar (which, by the way, is fine).